# list index out of range to extract text lines from a df column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I finally find as a need your guidance and support as I don't detect what is my error in the next piece of code.

It supposes that "list index out of range" rises when you initialize counter improperly to the length of df, but what I am attempting is to return the first then lines of the column `Descripción` as sample (doc) to apply the NLTK stopwords analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
stop_words = stopwords.words('spanish')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import string 


import base64
import re
from collections import Counter 


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import sklearn.feature_extraction.stop_words
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, roc_auc_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
import spacy
spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')
from spacy.lang.es import Spanish
parser = Spanish()


df = pd.read_csv('geografia_empleos_MX.csv')
df.head(2)

del df['Unnamed: 0']
df.head(1)


df.isnull().sum()

df1 = df.copy()

df1['fraudulento'].value_counts()



import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_lg')
stopwords = stopwords.words('spanish')


punctuations = string.punctuation


def limpia_texto(docs, logging = False):
    texts = []
    counter = 1
    for doc in docs:
       if counter % 100 == 0 and logging:
           print('Procesados: {} de {} documentos'.format(counter, len(docs)))
           counter += 1
           doc = nlp(doc, disable = ['parser', 'ner'])
           tokens = [tok.lemma_.lower().strip() for tok in doc if tok.lemma_ != '-PRON-']
           tokens = [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in stopwords and tok not in punctuations]
           tokens = ' '.join(tokens)
           texts.append(tokens)
   return pd.Series(texts)   

Falso_1 = [text for text in df1[df1['fraudulento'] == 1]['Descripción']]

Falso_1[10]    # Here is when index error raises :(
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falso_1 does not contain 10 indexes, that's why it raising an error. This line is collecting the columns from your dataframe.

```py
Falso_1 = [text for text in df1[df1['fraudulento'] == 1]['Descripción']]
```

You should replace it by the more pandas-like:

```py
Falso_1 = df1.loc[df1['fraudulento'] == 1, 'Descripción'].to_numpy()
Falso_1 .shape
```

`Falso_1.shape` will give you the number of indexes you have in it

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I applied the line you provided me above, and Falso_1.shape returns "(0,)" :s. And Falso_1[10] returns "IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0".  Now, I got a question about why it would transform the Pandas Series (texts) into Numpy Array, I mean, I am trying to return the first 10 lines of text from the column ('Descripción') which has the description of every job offer published and the boolean attribute fraud =1 or not fraud = 0

Comment: If Falso_1.shape returns (0,) it means that the test `df1['fraudulento'] == 1` didn't return True for any row of your dataframe. One possibility, is that 1 is stored as a string. To make sure, use `df1['fraudulento'].dtype`

Comment: you were right body!! df['fraudulento'].dtype returned string type = dtype('O'), so I changed the columns type with astype(int) method and finally run my code!! I appreciate your help! Thank you very much!